# where clause for collection always returning empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a model `Images` which pulls attributes such as `hidden` which will always be a `1` or `0`.

I've tried:

```
$all_images = Image::all();
var_dump($all_images->first()->hidden);
dd([
    $all_images->where('hidden', "0")->count(),
    $all_images->where('hidden', 0)->count(),
    $all_images->where('hidden', 1)->count(),
    $all_images->where('hidden', "1")->count()
]);


/* output
sController.php:219:string '1' (length=1)
array:4 [▼
0 => 0
1 => 0
2 => 0
3 => 0
]*/
```

but it's always returning 0.

But, if I do a raw query to the database using SQLite:

`17 rows returned in 0ms from: SELECT * FROM`images`WHERE`hidden`= '0';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all` will execute the query and return a collection. Instead use

```
dd([
    Image::where('hidden', "0")->count(),        
    Image::where('hidden', 1)->count(),        
]);
```

If you must use a collection then do:

```
dd([
   $allImages->filter(function ($value) { return $value->hidden == 0; })->count(),
   $allImages->filter(function ($value) { return $value->hidden == 1; })->count()
]);
```

Not sure if the collection's where works well with objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `->where(...)` on a collection instead of query builder.

```
// This line will return a collection -  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections
$all_images = Image::all();
```

**If you won't need both visible and hidden images**

```
// Collection does not have a method where(..)

// To get images that are "hidden" do this:
$hidden = Image::where('hidden', 0)->get(); // Again the result will be a collection

// To get images that aren't hidden do this:
$visible = Image::where('hidden', 1)->get(); // Will result in a collection
```

**If you need both visible and hidden images**

```
// If you need both visible and hidden you could load them all at once:
$images = Image::get();

// Then separate them with collection()->filter() - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter

$hidden = $images->filter(function ($v, $k) {
    return $images[$k]->hidden;
});

$visible = $images->filter(function ($v, $k) {
    return !$images[$k]->hidden;
});
```

Comment: The Collection class does have a where method; https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_where

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I had no idea. Nice find.